# Copying to user directory (java.nio)

Tags: java, file, operating-system, nio, copy-paste

I am writing a utility which is supposed to copy a file from its directory to the user's home directory (in Windows: C:\Users\\, and in UNIX /Users//). As you might have figured out, I am using `System.getProperties("os.get")` to determin what OS the utility is running on.

Now the problem is; whereas the users-folder is always (well usually) at the same place, the username, and hence the name of the user's home directory is variable. Does Java have a way to determin one's username, or alternatively the path to the home folder? I am using nio in Java7 to copy files (Files.move()).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
String UserHome = System.getProperty( "user.home" );
```

This will give you the User home directory on any platform.

Have a look at [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 2):

System.getProperty("user.home") is what you are looking for.